# Optimizing code mimiking sklearn kNN algorithm

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have written a script performing kNN classification using home-made functions. I have compared its performance against a similar script but using sklearn package.

Results :
House-Made ~ 20 seconds
sklearn ~ 2 seconds

So now I would like to know if the performance difference is mainly due to the fact that sklearn is executed at a lower level (in C as far as I understand) or because my script is not efficient.

If some of you got references providing information for writing efficient Python scripts and programs, I am all aware

Here is the data file : [DataFile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiw0ycthv7qmz9z/ESL.mixture.rda?dl=0)

**filename, os.environ['R_HOME'], os.environ['R_USER']** in both scripts must be made user-specific according to your directory structure

My code using home-made kNN classification

```
#Start Timer
import time
tic = time.time() 

# Begin Script
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\R\R-3.4.1' #setting temporary PATH variables : R_HOME
                                                                    #a permanent solution could be achieved but more complicated
os.environ['R_USER'] = r'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'
                                                                    #same story
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Read R data from ESLII book
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir, '../ESL.mixture.rda')
robjects.r['load'](filename) #load rda file in R workspace
rObject = robjects.r['ESL.mixture'] #read variable in R workspace and save it into python workspace

#Extract Blue and Orange classes data
classes = np.array(rObject[0]) #note that information about rObject are known by outputing the object into the console
                                #numpy is able to convert R data natively
BLUE = classes[0:100,:]
BLUE = np.concatenate((BLUE,np.zeros(np.size(BLUE,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1) 
        #the [:,None] is necessary to make the 1D array 2D. 
        #Indeed concatenate requires identical dimensions
        #other functions exist such as np.columns_stack but they take more time to execute than basic concatenate
ORANGE = classes[100:200]
ORANGE = np.concatenate((ORANGE,np.ones(np.size(ORANGE,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)
trainingSet = np.concatenate((BLUE,ORANGE),axis=0)

##create meshgrid
minBound = -3
maxBound = 4.5
xmesh = np.linspace(minBound, maxBound, 100)
ymesh = np.linspace(minBound, maxBound, 100)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xmesh, ymesh)
gridSet =np.stack((xv.ravel(),yv.ravel())).T

def predict(trainingSet, queryPoint, k):
    # create list for distances and targets
    distances = []
        # compute euclidean distance
    for i in range (np.size(trainingSet,0)):
        distances.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(trainingSet[i,:-1]-queryPoint))))
    #find k nearest neighbors to the query point and compute its outcome
    distances=np.array(distances)
    indices = np.argsort(distances) #provides indices, sorted from short to long distances
    kindices = indices[0:k]
    kNN = trainingSet[kindices,:]
    queryOutput = np.average(kNN[:,2])
    return queryOutput

k = 1
gridSet = np.concatenate((gridSet,np.zeros(np.size(gridSet,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)
i=0
for point in gridSet[:,:-1]:
    gridSet[i,2] = predict(trainingSet, point, k)
    i+=1


#k = 1
#test = predict(trainingSet, np.array([4.0, 1.2]), k)

col = np.where(gridSet[:,2]<0.5,'b','r').flatten() #flatten is necessary. 2D arrays are only accepted with RBA colors
plt.scatter(gridSet[:,0],gridSet[:,1],c=col,s=0.2)
col = np.where(trainingSet[:,2]<0.5,'b','r').flatten() #flatten is necessary. 2D arrays are only accepted with RBA colors
plt.scatter(trainingSet[:,0],trainingSet[:,1],c=col,s=1.0)
plt.contour(xv,yv,gridSet[:,2].reshape(xv.shape),0.5)
plt.savefig('kNN_homeMade.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()
#
#Stop timer
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic, 'sec Elapsed')
```

My code using sklearn kNN

```
#Start Timer
import time
tic = time.time() 

# Begin Script
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = r'C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\R\R-3.4.1' #setting temporary PATH variables : R_HOME
                                                                    #a permanent solution could be achieved but more complicated
os.environ['R_USER'] = r'C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\rpy2'
                                                                    #same story
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import neighbors

## Read R data from ESLII book
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir, '../ESL.mixture.rda')
robjects.r['load'](filename) #load rda file in R workspace
rObject = robjects.r['ESL.mixture'] #read variable in R workspace and save it into python workspace

#Extract Blue and Orange classes data
classes = np.array(rObject[0]) #note that information about rObject are known by outputing the object into the console
                                #numpy is able to convert R data natively
BLUE = classes[0:100,:]
BLUE = np.concatenate((BLUE,np.zeros(np.size(BLUE,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1) 
        #the [:,None] is necessary to make the 1D array 2D. 
        #Indeed concatenate requires identical dimensions
        #other functions exist such as np.columns_stack but they take more time to execute than basic concatenate
ORANGE = classes[100:200]
ORANGE = np.concatenate((ORANGE,np.ones(np.size(ORANGE,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)
trainingSet = np.concatenate((BLUE,ORANGE),axis=0)

##create meshgrid
minBound = -3
maxBound = 4.5
xmesh = np.linspace(minBound, maxBound, 100)
ymesh = np.linspace(minBound, maxBound, 100)
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xmesh, ymesh)
gridSet =np.stack((xv.ravel(),yv.ravel())).T
gridSet = np.concatenate((gridSet,np.zeros(np.size(gridSet,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)

##classify using kNN
k = 1
clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(k, weights='uniform',algorithm='brute')
clf.fit(trainingSet[:,:-1],trainingSet[:,-1:].ravel()) #learn, ravel necessary to obtain (n,) shape instead of a vector (n,1)
gridSet[:,2]  = clf.predict(np.c_[xv.ravel(), yv.ravel()])

#Plot
col = np.where(gridSet[:,2]<0.5,'b','r').flatten() #flatten is necessary. 2D arrays are only accepted with RBA colors
plt.scatter(gridSet[:,0],gridSet[:,1],c=col,s=0.2)
col = np.where(trainingSet[:,2]<0.5,'b','r').flatten() #flatten is necessary. 2D arrays are only accepted with RBA colors
plt.scatter(trainingSet[:,0],trainingSet[:,1],c=col,s=1.0)
plt.contour(xv,yv,gridSet[:,2].reshape(xv.shape),0.5)
plt.savefig('kNN_sciKit.png', dpi=600)
plt.show()
#
#Stop timer
toc = time.time()
print(toc-tic, 'sec Elapsed')
```

Comment: You might find it instructive to compare directly with the [`KNeighborsClassifier` source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py#L129).

Comment: That is a good idea. I should have thought of that. Thanks for the tip

Comment: The first thing which comes to mind: you are using sorting, they are using a kd-tree or ball-tree for potentially more efficient nearest-point lookups (common in kNN). But if that's a difference depends on the data.

Comment: Normally this has been disabled by forcing brute force algorithm for scikit kNN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following andrew_reece advice and performing some profiling on my code, I was to reduce the computation time to about 2 seconds (instead of 20 seconds).

The culprits were the two `for` loops in the following bit of code :

```
    def predict(trainingSet, queryPoint, k):
    # create list for distances and targets
    distances = []
    #targets = []

        # compute euclidean distance
    for i in range (np.size(trainingSet,0)):
        distances.append(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(trainingSet[i,:-1]-queryPoint))))
    #find k nearest neighbors to the query point and compute its outcome
    distances=np.array(distances)
    indices = np.argsort(distances) #provides indices, sorted from short to long distances
    kindices = indices[0:k]
    kNN = trainingSet[kindices,:]
    queryOutput = np.average(kNN[:,2])
    return queryOutput

k = 1
gridSet = np.concatenate((gridSet,np.zeros(np.size(gridSet,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)
i=0
for point in gridSet[:,:-1]:
    gridSet[i,2] = predict(trainingSet, point, k)
    i+=1
```

Reading the `neighbors` class from `sklearn` package, I noticed they performed euclidian distance computation in an entirely vectorized way. So I have read the code and now understand the function ... but I was lazy to completely re-write it. Instead, I just import the function `euclidean_distances` and use it directly with my data, therefore demonstrating the improvements. The modified part is found below:

```
    def predict(trainingSet, queryPoints, k):
    # create list for distances and targets
    distances = euclidean_distances(trainingSet[:,:-1],queryPoints[:,:-1]) #provides distances between each training point and each query point
    #line i is distance between training i and all query (in columns)
    #so k neighbors of query j are k first lines for column j
    #find k nearest neighbors to the query point and compute its outcome
    indices = np.argsort(distances,axis=0) #provides indices, sorted from short to long distances for each query point
    #kindices = indices[0:k]
    kNN = trainingSet[indices[:k,:],2] #produce the kNN outputs
    queryOutput = np.average(kNN,0)
    return queryOutput

k = 1
gridSet = np.concatenate((gridSet,np.zeros(np.size(gridSet,axis=0))[:,None]),axis=1)
gridSet[:,2] = predict(trainingSet, gridSet, k)
```